# WPF MVVM Light Exception not getting caught by Application_DispatcherUnhandledException

Tags: mvvm-light

Am using MVVM light toolkit for a WPF application. Somehow the Application_DispatcherUnhandledException method is not getting called for any exception thrown in the View/ViewModel. It gets called only if exception is thrown during load of the first Window(loaded by the app.xaml as the startup window) itself....then it simply doesn't get hit..
Anyone else facing this issue?

Thanks
Anshulee

Comment: Hi, the MVVM Light toolkit does not go to other threads by itself. Maybe your code does, but to make it sure, can you send me a simple repro and I will debug what happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the exception might not be occurring on the UI thread. I'm not sure what the framework is doing under the hood. Anyways, check this out:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90866/Unhandled-Exception-Handler-For-WPF-Applications.aspx
Non-UI threads are going to throw exceptions that your method by itself won't catch - you'll probably want to hook the AppDomain as well.

Comment: You sir saved my day! A freaking thread was throwing an exception and crashing the whole app! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM Light the exception from view models are not thrown in UI thread. Below code raise exception in UI thread

```
App.Current.RootVisual.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
            { 
                throw new MyException("Exception occured."); 
            });
```

Credit goes to this article http://codifying.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/silverlight-unhandled-exception-and-mvvm-light/